# How to get website root path from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net web site (use web forms). I have a class called `FileHandler` and inside that class I want to get the root path of the site.

Normally I use`Server.MapPath("~")` to get the path inside a web page.

Here I cannot use that because it is not a Page. How can I get the path of the web site?

**EDIT**
more about `FileHandler` class:
`FileHandler` is a static class and I am going to assign root path of the site to a satic variable.

Comment: Is it another project? If you add a reference to System.Web does that code work?

Comment: No. It is in the same project inside App_Code folder.

Comment: This is more a statement now than it is a question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had worked for me:

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("YOUR PATH");`

I have used this in a class separate from one of my pages. Normally you would be calling this not from HttpContext.

Comment: Ok this is what I really searched for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass it to the other class?

```
public class FileHandler {
    public string SiteRoot { get; set; }

    // or..
    public FileHandler(string siteRoot) {
        SiteRoot = siteRoot;
    }
}

FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler() { SiteRoot = Server.MapPath("~") };
// or..
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(Server.MapPath("~"));
```

Comment: `FileHandler` is a static class and i am going to assign this root path to satic variable

Answer (score 0):

One option would be that when you create a object of the `FileHandler` then pass the path as constructor parameter.

```
public class FileHandler 
{
   public FileHandler(string rootPath)
    {
       // store root path as a property
    }
}
```

Comment: FileHandler is a static class and i am going to assign this root path to satic variable.